# Why are my persimmons black beneath the hull?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees

My mother's persimmon tree is producing fruit that tastes good, but the area at the top beneath the leaves (the hull/calyx) is black. The local nursery suggested the fruit may be getting too much sunlight, but even fruits that have grown under the shade of other leaves have the same condition.

The leaves don't sit right on the fruit, like the persimmons we see in the store. Instead, there is a little bit of a gap between the fruit and those leaves.

Any ideas what may be causing this condition, and how we can prevent it next year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have black-spot, a fungal disease that attacks the fruit. When It attacks mature fruit in the orchard, it can be found almost entirely under the calyx. It is a high humidity that makes it spread, and it can be treated with a fungicide.